# Como tirar esse aviso Notice: Undefined index:

Tags: php, syntax-error

Tenho uma variável `$posicoes` que recebe a quantidade de elementos que existem na sessão respostas:

```
$posicoes = count($_SESSION['respostas']);
```

Dai eu verifico se o `GET` ***idQuestao*** é maior que a variavel ***posicoes***

```
if ($_GET['idQuestao'] > $posicoes) {
        // acontece isso... 
} else {
     $voltaQuestao = $idQuestao + 1;
     header("Location: questao.php?idQuestao=" . $voltaQuestao);
}
```

Dai fica aparecendo essa mensagem toda vez que a variavel posicoes for 0

> Notice: Undefined index: respostas in C:\wamp\www\quiz\questao.php on line 23

A linha 23 é essa: `$posicoes = count($_SESSION['respostas']);`

E eu preciso fazer essa verificação, ela tem que começar valendo **0** de qualquer jeito. A mensagem de erro some quando a variavel **posicoes** for maior ou igual a **1**?

Comment: Amigo formate melhor sua pergunta parece um tanto confusa ...
Mas se o problema for a mensagem mesmo não apresentando erro escreva:
error_reporting(0);
caso tenha um erro verifique o que esta  retornando no count e de um var_dump na variavel..

Verifique a $_SESSION['respostas'] se esta correta é minuscula mesmo..

Comment: As vezes você resolve o problema apenas dando um print_r($_SESSION); 
Você veria se a variável estava setada.

Answer (score 1):

Na linha **23**:

```
$posicoes = isset($_SESSION['respostas']) ? count($_SESSION['respostas']) : 0;
```

O [isset](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php) `(isset($_SESSION['respostas'])`, verifica se a variável foi inicializada, não dando mais o erro descrito como ***índice é indefinido***, ou seja, não existe!

**Referencia:**

- [***isset***](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php)

Comment: Muito obrigado, solucionou meu problema, esse dai é o operador ternário né?

Comment: Isso @ViniciusAquino fiz um ternário verificando se existe a `$_SESSION['respostas']` se sim ele mostra a quantidade se não atribui 0!